# How to get element from HTML sliding bar to a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this working script. It simply loop through and Object and display
the object key in HTML as sliding bar.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
   $('#threshold').change(updateThreshold);
   function updateThreshold () {
       var thresholdIndex = parseInt($('#threshold').val(), 10);
       $("#foldchange_threshold").html(foldchange_thresholds[thresholdIndex]);
   };

   var foldchange_thresholds = [];
    var mydata = {"3":["c","d"], "3.5":["j","k"], "1.5":["a","b"], "2.5":["x","y"] };
    
    Object.keys(mydata).sort().forEach(function(key) {
      foldchange_thresholds.push(key);
      
      });
      
    $('#threshold').attr('max', foldchange_thresholds.length-1);

  
   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
    <!-- Display the sliding bar -->
    <input id="threshold" type="range"  min="0" max="1" step="1" value="0" />
    <br>

    <!-- Show foldchange threshold -->
    <div id="foldchange_threshold" style="display: inline-block; align:center;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do, as user move the sliding bar, I'd like to get the element.

I am looking at something like these lines. But not sure where to put it.

```
var userFCchoice = document.getElementsByName('foldchange_threshold');
console.log(userFCchoice);
```

So if user slide to the value `3` the console log should print it out. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `.slider` functionality?

I've made a little example of getting the value to console.log, in the example below I'm using the `jquery-ui.min.js` and `jquery-ui.css` so that you can use the `.slider`.

`slide:` -
This section will show the value as `3` in the `console.log`

`change:` - This section will show the value in `foldchange_threshold` as `3.5`

`storedElementValue` - I've create this as a `global` variable to store the value of the `ui.value` for later use.

`.css()` - You can add the `.css()` to quickly add values of how you want to style the element or you could also use `.addClass()` to add a class to the slider and then you change the style in your `css` style sheet

```js
// Global variable to store value of the slider element
var storedElementValue = 0;

$(function($) {

  var foldchange_thresholds = [];
  var mydata = {
    "3": ["c", "d"],
    "3.5": ["j", "k"],
    "1.5": ["a", "b"],
    "2.5": ["x", "y"]
  };

  Object.keys(mydata).sort().forEach(function(key) {
    foldchange_thresholds.push(key);
  });

  $("#threshold").slider({
    min: 0, // min value
    max: foldchange_thresholds.length - 1, // max value
    step: 1,
    value: 0, // default value of slider
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      // Show console log of element value
      console.log(ui.value);
      storedElementValue = ui.value;
    },
    change: function(e, ui) {
      var thresholdIndex = parseInt(ui.value, 10);
      $("#foldchange_threshold").html(foldchange_thresholds[thresholdIndex]);
      $("#foldchange_threshold_storedValue").html("Stored value for later use: " + storedElementValue);
    }
  }).css("width", "200px");
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <!-- Display the sliding bar -->
  <div id="threshold"></div>
  <br>

  <!-- Show foldchange threshold -->
  <div id="foldchange_threshold" style="display: inline-block; align:center;"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="foldchange_threshold_storedValue" style="display: inline-block; align:center;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to store the value of `console.log(ui.value);` in an variable. Later will pass that variable to a function. How can I do that?

Comment: @neversaint Check my update answer, i've made an extra element called `foldchange_threshold_storedValue` to show the value which is stored for later use

Comment: @neversaint If there anything else, just ask :)

Comment: Can I make the slider shorter? Regardless number of steps.

Comment: @neversaint I've updated my answer to show you how you can change the style of the slider (slider length, regardless number of steps)

Answer (score 1):

No need for external plugins for this, jQuery is enough - You can attach your own `mousedown`, `mousemove`,`mouseup` combination to read the range input while dragging around:

[**JSnippet DEMO** - Input range live update while dragging](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/341/input-range-live-update-when-mouse-move)

```
   $(function() {  

     //Global variable that holds the value and updates while dragging.
     var valueTemp = 0;

     //Events functions:
     var changeEvent = function(){
         var thresholdIndex = parseInt($('#threshold').val(), 10);
         $("#foldchange_threshold").html($(this).val());
     };
     var downEvent = function(){
         $(this).bind('mousemove',moveEvent);
     };
     var moveEvent = function(){
         //trigger the change or comment it and do what ever you want:
         $(this).trigger('change');

         //Store the value into a variable available by other functions as asked in the comments:
         valueTemp = $(this).val();
         console.log($(this).val());
     };
     var upEvent = function(){
         $(this).unbind('mousemove');
     };
     
     //Bind events - mousemove is bind and unbind by the mousedown & mouseup events.
     $('#threshold').change(changeEvent);
     $('#threshold').mousedown(downEvent);
     $('#threshold').mouseup(upEvent);
  });
```

EDIT:

Afetr some comments here is an update with the working example that saves the value to a "global" variable while dragging:

[**JSnippet DEMO update** - Input range live update while dragging update](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/341/1/Input-range-live-update-while-dragging)

Comment: Thanks but I need to store `console.log($(this).val());` into a variable, later will pass it to a function. How can I do that?

Comment: @Shlomo: Thanks. Would you mind updating your DEMO in [**StackSnippet**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). You can use `CTRL-m` to enable.

Comment: Only JSnippet for me - here is an update: [update](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/341/1/Input-range-live-update-while-dragging)